# Dynamic SQL pivot returning only NULLs

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I am very new to dynamic SQL and am trying to construct a query to report on our workers, what certificates they have and what the expiry date is on their last certificate where one exists. My temp table holds the correct data and my dynamic column string seems to be correct. When everything is run, the column headings show as expected and the personnel names are grouped correctly but none of the dates are showing, the values are all NULL. I haven't put the specific code for the first 2 sections as the selection criteria is a bit long winded.

For the dynamic column variable, `SELECT STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '')` returns the single value below.

```
 [Air Supervisor - AODC], [Air Supervisor - IMCA], [ALST - Certificate of Achievement], [ALST - IMCA], [Competence - A1/A2 Competent Assessor], [Competence - Air Diver-Surface Supplied], etc...
```

The data itself is held in a temp table, `SELECT * FROM #results` gives the below (example) output. This is every cert matched to the relevant personnel ID with the most recent expiry date.

```
id      cert                            date
3484    [ALST - Banksman and Slinging]  28/07/2029
3648    [ALST - Banksman and Slinging]  05/11/2099
3701    [ALST - Banksman and Slinging]  27/05/2029
3740    [ALST - Banksman and Slinging]  20/01/2055
1181    [ALST - Crane Operators]        31/12/2029
1137    [ALST - Crane Operators]        31/12/2029
1072    [ALST - Crane Operators]        31/12/2029
```

The below is the actual pivot query. I need the [cert] field from above to become the column headers, dates (where they exist) to become the values and the personnel ID matched to the correct name.

```
SET @dynamicpivot =
        N'SELECT  pd.name, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '') + '
        FROM #results 
                PIVOT (MAX([date]) FOR [cert] IN (' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '') + ')) as ce
        JOIN dbo.personnel as pd
        ON pd.person_id = ce.id
        ORDER BY pd.name'

EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicpivot
```

The query runs without error, the column names show correctly and the personnel names show in order and grouped but none of the dates show, it's all NULLs.

I've tried to keep this fairly succinct, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise @columns.  The default value is NULL, which you cannot use in string concatenation.  This is because NULL cannot be combined with any other value.  For example NULL + 1 returns NULL and NULL + 'Some Text' also returns NULL.  You can test this with the below query.

**NULL Concatenation Example**

```
-- NULL cannot be concatenated.
SELECT
    NULL + 'ABC'
;
```

This returns NULL.  In effect your query is doing the same thing.

In this second example I'm using an initialised variable.  The lack of NULL allows me to concatenate values to the string.

**Initialised Variable Example**

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(255) = '';

-- Will return: 'ABC'.
SELECT
    @columns + 'ABC'
;
```

Alternativly you could achieve the same result using [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms184325.aspx).  This time the variable starts life as NULL.  This is replaced with a blank string during concatenation.

**ISNULL Example**

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(255) = NULL;

-- Using ISNULL returns: 'ABC'.
SELECT
    ISNULL(@columns, '') + 'ABC'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure this is the issue as the pivoted column headings show correctly. It's just the table values (dates) that are missing. I have `set @columns = N''
select @columns += N', ' + quotename((cty.CType + ' - ' + cty.desc))` at the start of the code block that creates the @columns variable, which I think covers the above, unless I'm missing something